# ComponentKit vs AsyncdisplayKit

Tags: ios, asyncdisplaykit, componentkit

I'm developing a social app, there is a main feature, "feeds".

so far It works with auto layout, everything is fine, but considering the cost of advanced development and maintenance in the future, I am looking for other async UI solutions.

I think ComponentKit, AsyncDisplayKit are what I looking for

but which one is better for me ?

both of them are supported async ui layout, and network image placeholder and cache ?

what's the difference between ComponentKit and AsyncDisplayKit ?

which one is better for complex feeds design ?

include : swift native / friendly, async ui layout, image cache & placeholder, complex feed style (horizontal cells in vertical cell) ... etc

Comment: This is the link that gives answer for your question I think: https://ios.libhunt.com/project/componentkit/vs/asyncdisplaykit

Comment: ... this is not what I want, i've read this before

Comment: Okay sorry. I thought you didn't

Comment: Did you ever get your answer? I'm curious as well!

Comment: ComponentKit is definitely not swift friendly because it use objc++. In our app, we use ComponentKit, but I love to use swift, so I write a wrapper for swift. https://github.com/leavez/ComponentSwift. You could have a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Component Kit` - Large Declarative (a lot of code by file) layouts without access to animation and frames.
`AsyncDisplayKit` - Small, laconic, declarative layouts, if you override layoutSubview method you can block `ASyncDisplayKit` to calculate frame, and do yourself animation by direct access to the view's frame.

My choice `AsyncDisplayKit` its more friendly, easy to make, hard layouts in minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I had been doing some research into both ComponentKit and AsyncDisplay kit and I think this [post](https://www.objc.io/issues/22-scale/facebook/#asyncdisplaykit) from Adam Ernst summaries it nicely:

> AsyncDisplayKit enables complex gesture-driven animations, precisely the area that is a weak spot for Components.
> This makes the choice easy:
>
> - If you’re designing a complex gesture-driven UI, AsyncDisplayKit might be right for you.
> - If your interface looks more like Facebook’s News Feed, Components could be a good fit.